# Is this reverse string code correct?

Tags: c++

This code works for me when I run it on my IDE, but it doesn't work on the website that has the exercise. I get a segmentation fault. So is this code correct? Did I make a mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string FirstReverse(string str) { 
  for (int i = 0, back = str.size()-1; i != back; ++i, --back)
  {
    char c = str[back];
    str[back] = str[i];
    str[i] = c;
  }
  return str; 
}

int main() {
  cout << FirstReverse("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

Also, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not use `std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end())`?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: What's exactly the error you get?

Comment: if the String is 4 letters, the i and back will never be equal... :p ... better stop iteration when i is equal or higher than str.size()/2

Comment: @Brandon I can't use that.

Comment: @mlwn It's a segmentation fault.

Comment: Check the answer below.. might work for you better :)

Comment: What if `str.size() == 0`?

Comment: Try some more test cases. In particular, try a string with an even length. And also an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index only needs to reach half of the length, and that way we ensure that the swap between a pair only happens once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size() / 2 ; i ++)
{
    char c = str[str.size() - 1 - i];
    str[str.size() - 1 - i] = str[i];
    str[i] = c;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you change the loop condition to "i <= back" then it won't cause segmentation fault. It is because when size-1 is even , i & back will never become equal. Thus loop will keep on going without breaking & attempt to access string member outside the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your condition from `!=` to `<=` and it will be solved.